# RS-232 Serial Merge

Tags: c

I'm looking for a simple solution to multiplex two RS-232 streams into a single RS-232 stream.  Both streams will be at a constant rate of 9600 BPS, and the output stream will be 19200 BPS.

I've considered using BS, Arduino, and Raspberry PI, but I would rather not re-invent the wheel if someone else has already implemented a similar solution.

Comment: This, in software, will require three items.  1) a function group to read RS232 stream #1 and communicate with the output function group. 2) a function group to read RS232 stream #2 and communicate with the output function. 3) a function group that gets its' inputs from function group #1 and #2 and writes to RS232 stream #3.  something like the POSIX msg utilities would work well for the communication between the function groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt you'll find any totally generic solution, because it's so rare that you can just merge two serial streams byte-by-byte - you nearly always have to deal with:

- arranging for whole packets (or lines) to be preserved,
- generally (perhaps not in your case with your faster output) have to have some kind of policy to deal with the possibility that data comes in faster than you can get rid of it.

But any hardware platform with 3 uarts will do this.  Personally I would prefer something with three real UARTs over some kind of USB host with a bunch of USB-serial adaptors hanging off it.